# Thread safety on Application Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, locking, application-start

I have an ASP.NET application in which I am writing this code in Application_OnStart event:

```
public virtual void OnStart(HttpApplication httpApplication)
{
    MyClass.PopulateIndices();
}
```

Now, I know that `App_Onstart` is fired only once, so my question is: do I need to add thread safety in this code, like:

```
lock(some object)
{
    MyClass.PopulateIndices();
}
```

Is this `lock()` really needed? Can multiple threads fire App `OnStart` simultaneously?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will be called just once. Definitely. You don't need any lock there.

From MSDN:

> The Application_Start method is called only one time during the life
>   cycle of an application.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

Comment: What if i am using same app's folder for a few website, it still called once ? How can i reproduce this ?

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with some logging and Application_Start is executed only once (while, for example, Session_Start is executed at every user' session start).

you won't need the lock.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you just `serviceAutoStartProviders` if you are using .NET 4.0 instead:

[Auto-Start ASP.NET Applications (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)